# How to capture a process's memory and current CPU usage at specified intervals

Tags: performance, memory, cpu, capture

requirement is to capture the following information in a single log file every 5 minutes for 4 processes (7005.exe, 7006.exe, 7007.exe, 7008.exe).

filename, memory used (kb), Cpu%, timestamp
7005.exe, 10240, 75, 10:30 AM
7006.exe, 10240, 75, 10:30 AM
7005.exe, 10242, 75, 10:35 AM
7006.exe, 10000, 75, 10:35 AM

I tried using task list but I am no good at command file scripting.

Please advise,

Thanks.

Comment: Can I use typeperf to capture memory used by each executable?

Answer (score 0):

do you want something like [sysinternals psList](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682.aspx) ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Windows Management Instrumentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and the [tasks/process API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in particular. There's an example on that page for gathering process CPU info via the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object.

Answer (score 0):

I have used these commands in a batch file, the only issue I have is to capture time the app name and memory usage. Any words of advise on how to capture date and time in the same line of the process?

```
echo %Date% %TIME% >> c:\ym\tasklist.log

tasklist /fi "memusage gt 100000" >> c:\tasklist.log
```

The output:

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
explorer.exe                   476 Console                    2    189,384 K
Maxthon.exe                   8104 Console                    2    275,540 K
OUTLOOK.EXE                   5320 Console                    2    189,992 K
Tue 10/09/2012 15:17:00.20 

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
explorer.exe                   476 Console                    2    187,936 K
Maxthon.exe                   8104 Console                    2    275,520 K
OUTLOOK.EXE                   5320 Console                    2    190,076 K
Tue 10/09/2012 15:19:00.35 

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
explorer.exe                   476 Console                    2    188,044 K
Maxthon.exe                   8104 Console                    2    300,520 K
OUTLOOK.EXE                   5320 Console                    2    190,080 K
```

The challenge for me is to bring the time-stamp next to each process. Someone advise please.